# Convert csv to xlsx splitting at “;” to different columns

Tags: python, excel, csv

im currently trying to convert a csv file to a xlsx file. 
I did find a lot of help on here how to do this but I have one major problem.

my csv file has some data stored in different columns. If I convert that file to xlsx in python, all data gets put into one column with a ";" between them. 
But how can I keep the columns in the xlsx file?

If I open the csv file and save it as xlsx it works too and everything stays the same.

EDIT:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

for csv_f in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csv_f[:-4] + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csv_f, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: what is the code you're using? and can you also post your sample dataframe?

Comment: I tested it with severeal different codes I found here in this forum. One example would be the Code in the answer below

Comment: As @anky_91 suggested, posting a sample of your data will give others a better chance of understanding your problem. Can you put something - even a couple of rows and columns that can allow others to reproduce the error with the code in the answer by Alex ?

Comment: Edited my post with 2 screenshots

Comment: strange.. @Kevin can you also post some of your code which gives you this trouble. Thank you.

Comment: I did as screenshot but its literaly exactly the same as in @Alex answer

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that the code you posted can't generate an xlsx file like the one in your screenshot. Because that looks an awful lot like an incorrectly opened csv file, not like a xlsx file.

Comment: I just tested it again, it is working! I deleted the xlsx file and after running the script it created exactly that xlsx file again

Comment: Alright, then please delete this question. A question with code that magically fixes itself isn't much use on SO.

Comment: Magically fixes itself? It stills creates that wrong xlsx file! Its still everything in one column

Comment: With "its working!" I was refering that you are sure the code cant create a file like that. It is 100% creating exactly this faulty xlsx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it!

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
   workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
   worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
   with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
       for r, row in enumerate(reader):
           for c, col in enumerate(row):
               str(worksheet.write(r, c, col)).split(";")
   workbook.close()
```

The important thing here is the `"delimiter=";"` in that line:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how you can convert csv to xlsx via `xlsxwriter`

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


    for csv_f in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
        workbook = Workbook(csv_f[:-4] + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        with open(csv_f, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    worksheet.write(r, c, col)
        workbook.close()
```

Comment: You didnt understand my question I think. I already did find this solution but it only copys the whole csv file into one column with a ";" between them. Thats not what I want. I want column A to be written into column A, then B to B etc